# Vue: cant do pagination from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm creating a movie website using TMDB API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies)
I want to show 20 movies in the homepage and then show another 20 movies when I click next.

Here's my Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <MovieList v-bind:movies="movies" :showMovies="showMovies"/>
    <div class="my-4"> <!-- Pagination -->
      <ul class="pagination pagination-md justify-content-center text-center">
            <li class="page-item" :class="page === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''">
              <a class="page-link" @click="prevPage">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-link" style="background-color: inherit">
                1
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" :class="page === lastPage ? 'disabled' : ''">
              <a class="page-link" @click="nextPage">Next</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import MovieList from '../components/MovieList'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  components: {
    MovieList
  },
  data: function() {
        return {
            movies : null,
            page: 1,
            loading: false,
            perPage: 20
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            var that = this
            axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=e7bb075c43180bc41bffe6004eb81113&language=en-US&page=' + this.page)
                 .then(function(response) {
                    that.movies = response.data.results
                })
        },
        prevPage () {
            this.page--
        },
        nextPage () {
            this.page++
        },
        lastPage () {
            let length = this.movies.length 
            return length / this.perPage
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getData()
    }


}
</script>
```

I'm guessing that there's something wrong with my getData() function but I can't seem to solve it.
Anyone knows what did I do wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are not calling getData after nextPage/prevPage when the user clicks on them.

Comment: First, why are you calling all those methods into mounted() hook? You might just call getData() when mounted. 
Second, I would advise to add another line into your prevPage() and nextPage() methods: once the page was changed, just call again getData().

Comment: @SaudQureshi Ah I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @JBA thank you for your explanation, much appreciated! I'm sorry if it's strange because I'm new to Vue and still understanding about it. I did not put those methods before, but I did it later because I was experimenting. Who knows if it could work. Very sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update `prevPage` and `nextPage` function
```

```js
        prevPage () {
          this.page = this.page--;
          this.getData();
        },
        nextPage () {
          this.page = this.page++;
          this.getData();
        },
```

Comment: Works really well! Thank you so much!